# Trigger image onload using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, onload

My situation is that i need to check the size of an image using javascript and then execute a piece of code depending on its width.Here is my code

```
        var width, height;
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "pool.jpg";
        img.onload = function () {
            width = this.width;
            height = this.height;
            console.log(width);
        }
        console.log(width);

        if (width > 0) {
            console.log('in condition check');
            //Some code to be executed
        }
        //Some other code to be executed which cannot be put in the onload portion
```

the issue is that the `img.onload` portion works only after the below code has finished execution.Is there any way to trigger the `img.onload` function and go in a synchronous way of code execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't make your code wait until the external task (usually involving a server) has finished execution.

You **have** to put your code in the callback (or in a function called from the callback) :

```
   img.onload = function () {
        width = this.width;
        height = this.height;
        console.log(width);
        if (width > 0) {
           console.log('in condition check');
           //Some code to be executed
        }
    }
```

To build JavaScript applications, you must learn to deal with event-based programming, where most of your code act upon events, be them user actions or asynchronous task completions.

*(technically there is a way but don't use it)*

Comment: It uses xmlhttprequest but is much more complete and a terrible practice that nobody uses because when you're able to use it you're experienced enough to learn the asynchronous way which doesn't block the interface. You need to learn how to deal with asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wait for the callback, then you can pass the result to another function:

```
var width, height;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://kushsrivastava.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/test.gif";
    img.onload = function () {
        width = this.width;
        height = this.height;
        console.log(width);
        if (width > 0) {
            console.log('in condition check');
            //Some code to be executed
            haveFun(width);
        }
    }
    var haveFun = function(w) {
        console.log('Im having fun with ' + w );
    }
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juaning/LQByS/) with a lil' sample.